# Error when trying to install cmake

Tags: package-management, cmake

I get this error message when trying to install cmake.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cmake-data libjsoncpp1 librhash0 libuv1
Suggested packages:
  cmake-doc ninja-build
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cmake cmake-data libjsoncpp1 librhash0 libuv1
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,332 kB/4,497 kB of archives.
After this operation, 23.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main arm64 cmake-data all 3.10.2-1ubuntu2.18.04.1
  Could not resolve 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/c/cmake/cmake-data_3.10.2-1ubuntu2.18.04.1_all.deb  Could not resolve 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I have seen an answer regarding this over here, but had difficulties with this and couldn't understand it.

Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

Check the word after http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ in the sources.list file, let the word be xyz

Go to the address http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ and then click on dists.

Now check whether xyz is present at this path. If it is not present, then replace xyz with the element which is present in 'dists' such as:- saucy, lucid, trusty etc.

Now run `sudo apt-get update` command.

Comment: Your question is hard to read  (use code {} formatting tags around pastes), and heading information should be repeated in question text (headings are not always visible when reading question on some devices).  I selected one file your are trying to download and have no issues, so I'd check your network, firewalls or proxy you may be behind...

Comment: `Could not resolve 'ports.ubuntu.com'` definitely sounds like a networking (DNS lookup) issue